# Packeto built image raises command not found

Tags: python, docker, image, flask, paketo

I have following pieces of code

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

      app = Flask(__name__)

      @app.route("/")
      def hello():
      return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

      app.run()
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0.2
```

Procfile

```
web: python server.py
```

All files are in the same directory.

I run

```
pack build flask-app --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/python
```

to build the image.

When running the image inside a container with

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 flask-app -d
```

I get

```
python server.py: python server.py: command not found
```

Also using

```
web: gunicorn server:app
```

(and adding gunicorn in the requirements.txt) fails.

I have no idea why

[EDIT]

Here is the output of `pack build`

```
base: Pulling from paketobuildpacks/builder
Digest: sha256:b180767fe81f7d33a873a631a52f58fa72e4f64615e659abc86e2b6c1e0d1467
Status: Image is up to date for paketobuildpacks/builder:base
base-cnb: Pulling from paketobuildpacks/run
Digest: sha256:690ba86ac3a921b459a562627a7b3c8412be4abcfde5c1dc9b670bdcb7641873
Status: Image is up to date for paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb
===> ANALYZING
Previous image with name "flask-app" not found
===> DETECTING
6 of 9 buildpacks participating
paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates 3.5.0
paketo-buildpacks/cpython         1.7.3
paketo-buildpacks/pip             0.16.1
paketo-buildpacks/pip-install     0.5.7
paketo-buildpacks/python-start    0.14.0
paketo-buildpacks/procfile        5.4.0
===> RESTORING
Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/pip:pip" from cache
Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/pip-install:cache" from cache
Restoring data for "paketo-buildpacks/pip:pip" from cache
Restoring data for "paketo-buildpacks/pip-install:cache" from cache
Restoring data for SBOM from cache
===> BUILDING

Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.5.0
  https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
  Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
    Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
Paketo Buildpack for CPython 1.7.3
  Resolving CPython version
    Candidate version sources (in priority order):
                -> ""
      <unknown> -> ""

    Selected CPython version (using ): 3.10.8

  Executing build process
    Installing CPython 3.10.8
      Completed in 8.072s

  Generating SBOM for /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython
      Completed in 0s


  Configuring build environment
    PYTHONPATH          -> "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython"
    PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX -> "/tmp"

  Configuring launch environment
    PYTHONPATH -> "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython"

Paketo Buildpack for Pip 0.16.1
  Resolving Pip version
    Candidate version sources (in priority order):
      <unknown> -> ""

    Selected Pip version (using <unknown>): 22.3.1

  Reusing cached layer /layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip/pip
Paketo Buildpack for Pip Install 0.5.7
  Executing build process
    Running 'pip install --requirement requirements.txt --exists-action=w --cache-dir=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/cache --compile --user --disable-pip-version-check'
      Completed in 3.165s

  Generating SBOM for /layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages
      Completed in 2ms

  Configuring build environment
    PYTHONPATH -> "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"

  Configuring launch environment
    PYTHONPATH -> "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"

Paketo Buildpack for Python Start 0.14.0
  Assigning launch processes:
    web (default): python


Paketo Buildpack for Procfile 5.4.0
  https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/procfile
  Process types:
    web: python server.py
===> EXPORTING
Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates:helper'
Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/cpython:cpython'
Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/pip-install:packages'
Adding layer 'launch.sbom'
Adding 1/1 app layer(s)
Adding layer 'launcher'
Adding layer 'config'
Adding layer 'process-types'
Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
Setting default process type 'web'
Saving flask-app...
*** Images (e9fb80d3820a):
      flask-app
Reusing cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/cpython:cpython'
Reusing cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/pip:pip'
Adding cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/pip-install:cache'
Reusing cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/pip-install:packages'
Reusing cache layer 'cache.sbom'
Successfully built image flask-app
```

Comment: Can you post the full output from `pack build`? That'll show what is happening. It looks like your start command is being set, but it's odd that python isn't on the path. Anyway, the output of the build operation will show more details.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I added the output

Comment: Interestingly, the image works fine when running it in a container which is NOT in detached mode

Comment: SOLVED: This issue is not paketo-related. The ´d-´ flag is not allowed to be set after the image name